# Loading a JavaScript file dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I was asked to add this code to my pitch pages by the vendor I sell through:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var p = '/?vendor=2knowmysel&time=' + new Date().getTime();
        var cb = document.createElement('script'); cb.type = 'text/javascript';
        cb.src = '//header.clickbank.net' + p;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cb);
    })();
</script>
```

The code should let the page load within a header that has a red logo by clickbank. When I added the code in the head section nothing happened.

Next I tried to isolate the problem by posting on a blank html page (away from drupal) which is http://www.2knowmyself.com/testpage.htm.

But the frame doesn't show up.

What's wrong in here? Given clickbank claim the code is perfect.

Comment: What if you add it just before </body>? It seems that you are trying to append a script to the head, before the head is finished loading.

Comment: this code makes an HTTP request to Clickbank and is getting a response code of `204 No Content`.  You're being sent an empty script so there's nothing to execute and no logo to display.

Comment: Hi @DanO  they just implemented the system, maybe they didn't add the data yet?  so my question is, from my side , is eveyrthing working?

Comment: I'm getting `404` here, when trying to access the script. But the `script` that your page is running, itself, seems to work. Now, how is it related to iframes?

Comment: Yes OP, from your side, everything seems to be working as expected.

Comment: thank you so much guys
as for my mention of frames,i am not a programmer, so this code doesnt load iframe? i would be very thankful if someone explained what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your code does:

```
<script>
    // the following line creates an anonymous immediately-invoked function
    (function() {
        // this will return a string named 'p', which contains the vendors ID and current time
        var p = '/?vendor=2knowmysel&time=' + new Date().getTime();
        // this creates a new 'script' tag for HTML, name it 'cb', and tells the code it's for JavaScript
        var cb = document.createElement('script'); cb.type = 'text/javascript';
        // this will take a url with the address and the query string, which you named 'p' earlier, and set it as the source for 'cb'
        cb.src = '//header.clickbank.net' + p;
        // now you'll insert 'cb' to the HTML, so it'll load the JavaScript file into it
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cb);
    // the function won't run automatically upon declaration, so you use parenthesis to tell it to run
    })();
</script>
```

**Summing it up**, it bassically sends the vendor's ID and current time to the given server, and expects a JavaScript file in return from it; it'll then load this file into your HTML document.

Currently, it seems not to be working because this server is getting the information from your page but not sending the JavaScript file back to it. When they adjust it to answer with the right file, you'll see it run accordingly.

**EDIT:** (to answer your Final Question)

Up to this point, I can see that their server isn't sending the expected JS file back at your page, so it doesn't work. If you want to check this by yourself, please use a JS debugger or a network monitor in your browser (most of the modern webbrowsers come with these built-in, try pressing F12 then reloading the page).

If you want to check whether iframes work on your server, you may contact its administrator or try to embed an iframe in the page yourself. Paste the following code into the document. If you see SO homepage, it works. Otherwise, it'll show nothing.  If you see `Your browser does not support iframes.`, then you might have to update your web browser and check it again.

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" width="300" height="300">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: thank you so much every body. very useful, Final question. they sent me this info with the installation guide 

"The ClickBank header loads your pages inside of an iframe.  Having iframes blocked entirely will inhibit the functionality of the page. Make sure your webserver configuration allows your pages to load within a frame."


how do i know this is not the problem?

Comment: I hope this helps. If this has solved your question, I ask you kindly to select this answer as the accepted one; this gives me reputation and motivates me to help others.

Comment: @MohamedFarouk, up to this point, the problem is that their server isn't sending the JS file back. I can guarantee you this, but you can check this yourself with a JavaScript debugger in your web browser or checking the network monitor in your browser when the page loads. If you are worried about whether your server allows or not `iframe`, you can contact the administrator of your webserver.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the 200 rep I needed :D. I've updated the answer btw, check it and see if this helps. Have a good day!